# How do I store a process variable to a global variable in KIE Workbench? (jBPM 7)

Tags: drools, jbpm, kie, kie-workbench

I have a global Integer variable `RANDOM_NUMBER`

I just want to store the response from a service that returns a random number into that global variable. How do I do that in the workbench?

So basically `RANDOM_NUMBER = result`

**Business process:**

[image: Business process]

**Variables:**

[image: Python Variables]

**Service Data I/O:**

[image: Data I/O]

Comment: I have a question, how does your "Call Python Service via Kong" step work? What screen is the "Service Data I/O" setup on that you have screenshotted? We're trying to figure that out here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56635406/calling-a-rest-service-using-business-central-and-jbpm

Comment: @JonathanS.Fisher I have a Python microservice that is returning some data. I am storing that data in a process variable and using that process variable in the next step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, but I can't say I tested carefully, that global variables are shared between processes or process instances and process data is available to a specific process instance.

EDIT: So you can save the result of a workitem into a process variable but you have to use code to access the global variables. See section [8.6.1. Variables](https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/release/7.22.0.Final/jbpm-docs/html_single/#_variables) of the documentation.

The issue will be that "result" isn't available as a variable in the context of the exit script. It's an output parameter of the workitem. So, in order to get the result of the workitem into a variable that then can be copied into a global variable create a process variable (in your case *result* though I'm not a fan of the duplicate name) and assign result to that, which it looks like you did.

So probably the script on the exit script of the REST workitem should be.

```
kcontext.getKieRuntime().setGlobal("RANDOM_NUMBER", Integer.parseInt(result.trim()));
```

Comment: The thing is I don't have a drop down option for in the target section for my Global `RANDOM_NUMBER`.

Comment: Should the GlobalVariable show up in the Target drop-down?

Comment: I've even tried `RANDOM_NUMBER = Integer.parseInt(result.trim());` on the on-entry action and on-exit action but each time, RANDOM_NUMBER is not being initialized. I have no idea what is going on.

Comment: You can't parse from a String to an Integer. To fix that I just did `Integer.parseInt(result.trim())`. Thanks you are a life saver. Been on this for hours now lol.

Comment: How do I check the global variable to ensure it's value?

Comment: I really haven't tried working with global variables. You could check the database or maybe add a script task that reads it and does a `System.out.println` for the next step. Or, of course, add another process with a script task that does `System.out.println` and start the process afterwards.