# Calling a REST service using business central and JBPM

Tags: java, rest, drools, jbpm

We're trying to do a POC showing we can call an external REST service using JBPM in business-central.

We've created a new BPM, then added a REST service task. We notice at this point that a WID file is created that has REST definition. Inside the WID file, it defines things like URL, Method, and authentication.

We've sifted through all the 7.2 docs, but for the life of us, we cannot figure out how to actually set those parameters and do something useful. Does anyone have a simple "Hello World" using business central 7.2 calling out to an external process?

We see there's a predefinied REST handler: https://github.com/kiegroup/jbpm/blob/master/jbpm-workitems/jbpm-workitems-rest/src/main/java/org/jbpm/process/workitem/rest/RESTWorkItemHandler.java

We're lacking how to assemble all of this; we can't find documentation or examples on something that seems so simple.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Busines Central, you can edit the process model and check the data assignments for the specific REST node. In there you can set the values of the variables or use some process variable to map dynamic values. Hope it helps.

[image: Process modeler variables]

Comment: Holy smokes. Thank you so much, that critical piece is hidden deep in the UI

Comment: Followup, we're getting a "Unable to create response: [.jonathan.RestfulCallout:6 - REST:1] -- Could not find work item handler for Rest" Looks like we're missing that JAR. How do you add it to the project? I tried uploading jbpm-workitems-rest to the server but it failed

Comment: Figured it out after watching https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_XIZ0KRTahE we added a work item handler definition called "Rest"

Comment: @Cristiano, if we're not using Business central, then?